# operator method? non-autonomous differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

Professor told me that solving:

$\ddot{\theta}+\dot{\theta} +f(\theta) = c_0 \times \delta(t)$

can be done by taking a limit

$\lim_{e \to 0} \int_{-e}^{e} \left ( \ddot{\theta}+\dot{\theta} +f(\theta) \right) dt  = c_0\lim_{e \to 0} \delta(t)$,
$$\lim_{e \to 0} \int_{-e}^{e} \left ( \ddot{\theta}+\dot{\theta} +f(\theta) \right) dt  = c_0,$$
(where in the right part dirac - delta function goes to 1.)

But how can I receive on the left part of the equation?:

$[\dot\theta]$, so that

$[\dot\theta] = c_0.$ <- it was said that this is the answer. 
Here is professors handwriting:
[image]
Only thing I can guess is that, and it is only a guess, that

$\lim_{e \to 0} \int_{-e}^{e} f(\theta) = 0$

> Dear  grdgfgr Thank you. Still some unclear questions: 1) what do you
>   mean by writing wrt t? 2) what is the dirac delta derivative? Does it
>   exist ? If I look on the definition, I see that it equals infinity at
>   0, and 0 else, that is why I suppose it is not defined.. 3) I did not
>   understand how you say that the jump can be only in $\ddot{\theta}$
>   case. BUT! While writing this question I think, I have realized, could
>   you be pleased, to say am I right?
>
> I got that $\dot{\theta(e)} - \dot{\theta(-e)}$ or $\theta(e) -
> > \theta(-e)$ or $F(\theta(e)) - F(\theta(-e))$ should have somewhere
>   the value $c_0$ to be consistent with LHS.
>
> If I look at the condition that $e \to 0$, I understand that all this
>   3 differences are going to be equal 0.  But I go from the last one. I
>   assume that function is smooth enough therfore $F(\theta(e)) -
> > F(\theta(-e)) = 0$, as well as   $\theta(e) - \theta(-e) = 0 $,
>   however, what I think is:
>
> differnce $\dot{\theta(e)} - \dot{\theta(-e)}$ can be the jump,
>   because, when I have a saddle point, or a peak, the values of the
>   derivatives of some variable at  $e$ and $-e$ positions can be very
>   different especially in 2 close positions.    Is this the logic, why
>   you say that the jump can be only in $\dot{\theta}$?

Comment: Were you supposed to integrate wrt $\theta$

Comment: pardon, I do not understand,to add,  as far as I understand $[\dot\theta]$ means that it is a jump of the value $\dot\theta $

Comment: Why would $\delta$ go to 1, it makes no sense. Is it supposed to be dirac delta?

Comment: yes, it is a dirac delta.

Comment: You should also integrate the right part wrt t. It doesn't make sense any other way.

Comment: How can I integrate this : $$\lim_{e \to 0} \int_{-e}^{e} \left ( \ddot{\theta}+\dot{\theta} +f(\theta) \right) dt $$ ? Integral of $\ddot{\theta}$, I am not sure, but $\dot{\theta}$, but what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this question but I think this is what is supposed to happen:

$$\ddot{\theta}(t)+\dot{\theta}(t) +f(\theta(t)) = c_0 \times \delta(t)$$

Integrate both sides wrt t

$$\int^{\epsilon}_{-\epsilon}\bigg(\ddot{\theta}(t)+\dot{\theta} (t)+f(\theta(t))\bigg) dt=\int^{\epsilon}_{-\epsilon} c_0 \times \delta(t)dt$$

Integral of $\delta$ is $1$. $F(\theta(t))$ is the antiderivative of $f(\theta(t))$. We get:

$$\dot{\theta}(\epsilon)-\dot{\theta}(-\epsilon)+\theta(\epsilon)-\theta(-\epsilon)+F(\theta(\epsilon))-F(\theta(-\epsilon))=c_0$$

Now since $\epsilon$ is so small, normally the left side should have been 0. But this indicates one of those functions must have a jump. Jump has to be caused by a delta in $\ddot{\theta}(t)$ since if it were caused by, for example, $\dot{\theta}(t)$, then $\ddot{\theta}(t)$ would contain a dirac delta derivative, which we dont see on RHS.

Update:

wrt : with respect to.

dirac delta derivative is complicated to explain, but if you had the derivative of dirac delta, you would certainly need to take that into account. But we don't see such a think on the RHS (right hand side) so we can say that neither $\dot{\theta}(t)$ nor $\theta (t)$ may contain dirac delta.

[image]

you can consider delta to be the derivative of this step function. And the integral of delta to be this step function.

so $\dot \theta$ in this example looks like the step function above.

This is a 1D function, it can't have a saddle point. We also are not concerned by peaks.

Comment: Could not write my comment/question here. Look please on my main question bottom.

Comment: Integral of $\ddot \theta (t) $ is $\dot \theta (t)$. Integral and derivative are inverse operations. That dot is derivative.

Comment: Could you be pleased to look at the main question? I made an update in yellow background colour.

Comment: @Ievgenii I updated.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the wrong terminology, I meant peaks and saddle point just to explain that I have some bend. I.e. if I go from left to right($-e \to 0$) I have , for example, incline of $\theta$, but if I go from right to left($e \to 0$) I have, for instance, decline of $\ theta $, that is why the derivative near the decline and incline differ not only by value, but by sign, and therefore we have a jump. Thank you,  grdgfgr, again :-)

Comment: And this is, as far as I understand, you did on the picture above.